# Best Way To Insert Data From One Table to Another..Triggers, Power Shell, Tasks?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table in a database that grows over time. If there are more than 5000 records, the data should take the last 4000 leaving the latest 1000 behind and move it to another table. Is there an automated way of doing this?

I know we can run a trigger and count every time. I would like to avoid that trigger if possible.

I know we can run a job every so often which executes a stored procedure. This can then count the records and perform the desired action.

I know we can run a power shell or batch file that will execute a stored procedure through the task scheduler.

Is there any other way? Triggers stop processes and jobs rely on the server agent and tasks rely on the task manager.

If I could choose one with the greatest reliability, I think it would be through the task scheduler. Am I wrong in saying this? I define reliability as the length of time an operation can stay in operation to give the desired output without fail.  Any insight or suggestions in how to better handle this would be great. Thanks.

Comment: 5,000 rows in a table is not very large.  This archiving is probably not the best solution to your actual problem.

Comment: All are equally reliable to the point of any difference being negligible.  Triggers and .exes are a great way to forget about code though.  I would recommend a daily SQL job that checks the count and archives if needed.  If your SQL Agent is down, you probably have bigger issues.

Comment: Agreed with Gordon here. 5000 is a trivial amount. One thing you can also do it partition your tables between active and not active data. Set the partitions to two different file groups one on a slow history drive and one on a super fast SSD..... but then what's the point 5000 is tiny.

Comment: Thanks for the advice about the jobs. I agree I would have bigger issues if the server agent is down. I also agree 5000 is tiny, however it does have a performance hit due to the heavy IO traffic load. Any more records than 5000, then the processor time starts to go above the desired %.

Comment: I agree with all the comments above. If I had to choose, I would go with an sql server scheduled job.

Comment: 4000 records is nothing. You can use a trigger and not worry about the delay. SQL jobs use local time and will stop for one hour per year if you are using DST.